# how can i use number sprite to display score in cocos2d-x using c++?

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have numbers in `sprites` (eg-0.png,1.png,2.png,3.png,4.png etc..) i would like to use these numbers to display **score** as well as **high score** in `cocos2d-x` using `c++` in `xcode`. I really appreciate if someone can help me with source code. Thanks in advance.

```
cocos2d::LabelBMFont* label = cocos2d::LabelBMFont::create(std::to_string(score), 
                                                          "Marker Felt");
label->setAlignment(cocos2d::TextHAlignment::CENTER);
addChild(label, 0);
label->setPosition(...);
```

I can display using `Label`. But dont know how to use number `images` to display score.

Comment: so these sprites are numbers that you want to display as score. That seems intensive. I think most people use `Labels`. I mean at some point you have to evaluate the score and decide what Sprites to show to make up your score.

Comment: Use Littera tool to generate texture and fnt file from TTF font file then you can easily use with LabelBMFont